# The application xyz has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again

Tags: android

I developed an `android` application and it worked perfectly at first for a few days. But later, when I checked, it is not working. Now when I used to start it in my device or emulator, it shows the message like **The application xyz has stopped unexpectedly.Please try again.** Can anybody help me?

This is my Logcat

```
12-31 20:20:52.142: D/AndroidRuntime(303): Shutting down VM
12-31 20:20:52.172: W/dalvikvm(303): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{a.b.c/a.b.c.MapsActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: a.b.c.MapsActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/a.b.c-2.apk]
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: a.b.c.MapsActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar:/data/app/a.b.c-2.apk]
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
12-31 20:20:52.202: E/AndroidRuntime(303):  ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Your App has a BUG.

Check LogCat to see what happens, maybe it's a untreated exception.

Answer (score 0):

Try to

add "uses-library" like this in your manifest file.

```
     <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     package="com.example.package.name">
      ...
      <application android:name="MyApplication" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        ...
      </application>
     ...
    </manifest>
```

And clean and rebuild your project and try out.

If that doesn't work please try to add some code so that we can look into that.

Comment: That's the same I used in my manifest and I was perfectly fine with the app, but for a couple of days only; it is showing the current error.